# variable isn't passed to the view, when using resource controller in laravel

Tags: laravel

i've a resource route `Route::resource('orders', 'BackendController');` in my application. in the routes list, it has `orders/{order}/edit` route for edit order, and `orders/{order}` for update order. in the `edit-order.blade.php` it has `<form>` tag. inside the form tag, i've defined `action="{{route('orders.update',$order->id)}}" method="post"` also put `@csrf & @method('PUT')`. in my `BackendController` i've edit & update functions, seen below ->

```
public function edit(Order $order){
   return view('backEnd.edit-order', compact('order'));
}

public function update(Request $request, Order $order){
    $order->address             = $request->address;
    $order->city                = $request->city;
    $order->state               = $request->state;
    $order->appointment         = $request->appointment;
    $order->client              = $request->client;
    $order->special_instruction = $request->special_instruction;
    $order->first_name          = $request->first_name;
    $order->last_name           = $request->last_name;
    $order->mobile_phone        = $request->mobile_phone;
    $order->home_phone          = $request->home_phone;
    $order->email               = $request->email;
    $order->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

looks like i'm passing the `$order` variable which the route requires to the `edit-order.blade.php` but i'm getting error -> `undefined variable order`. what is going wrong here ? and how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you passed `order` variable to your views? Something like `compact('order')`

Comment: yeah @RouhollahMazarei

Comment: Put complete code, your methods and views please.

Comment: view is too long to show here, i've edited the functions according to the fields of the view

Comment: in the edit function, what are you doing before returning a view?

Comment: die dump the order variable before returning view and see if route model binding for order variable works!

Comment: nothing, just passing the variable as shown @MihirBhende

Comment: What is the purpose of $order if it is not holding any value? Do you want the instantiation of it given by Laravel's dependency injection?

Comment: Can you show your edit route declaration please?

Comment: @MihirBhende please look at the code above edit route action is already there

Comment: in the controller i've used App\Order model, so the public function edit(Order $order) will pass the whole model values to the view, isn't that the idea of resource controller ? @MihirBhende

Comment: How about `{{route('orders.edit', [ 'order' => $order->id]) }}`. Can you please show how you are calling edit route?